# SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file

Tags: spring, tomcat

While tomcat starts, getting  following error.
OS : Linux
Tomcat Version : apache-tomcat-8.0.33

```
    Jun 10, 2016 5:06:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
    SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
    Jun 10, 2016 5:06:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
    SEVERE: Context [/comprofile] startup failed due to previous errors
    Jun 10, 2016 5:06:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
    Jun 10, 2016 5:06:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
    SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:39)
        at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:45)
        at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:73)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:242)
```

Comment: Probably slf4j-over-log4j and log4j-over-slf4j are both present on the classpath, resulting in infinite recursion.

Comment: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#log4jDelegationLoop

Comment: Issue fixed. Thank you all

Comment: @RamasubramaniamR Please tell us how you have solved it.